# Como mudar o top do v-select

Tags: vue.js, vuetify

Há alguma forma de eu mudar o "top" da lista do v-select sem eu precisar forçar um css? exemplo:
[image: 1]

Como eu gostaria que ficasse:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Me parece então que você está utilizando o componente com a finalidade de uso diferente.

Para esse caso existe o Combobox do vuetify.

[Componente Combobox - Vuetify](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/combobox/)